# PYTHONPATH issue on google colab

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, google-colaboratory, apt

From different forum and tutorial it seem that the command
`!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py` supposed to give an output like:

```
Running tests under Python 3.6.9: /usr/bin/python3
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_experimental_model
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_experimental_model
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_model_from_config_with_example_miner
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_model_from_config_with_example_miner
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_with_matmul
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_with_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_without_matmul
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_faster_rcnn_without_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_with_matmul
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_with_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_without_matmul
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_faster_rcnn_models_from_config_mask_rcnn_without_matmul
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_rfcn_model_from_config
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_rfcn_model_from_config
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_ssd_fpn_model_from_config
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_ssd_fpn_model_from_config
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_ssd_models_from_config
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_create_ssd_models_from_config
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_faster_rcnn_batchnorm_update
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_faster_rcnn_batchnorm_update
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_first_stage_nms_iou_threshold
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_first_stage_nms_iou_threshold
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_model_config_proto
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_model_config_proto
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_second_stage_batch_size
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_invalid_second_stage_batch_size
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_session
[  SKIPPED ] ModelBuilderTest.test_session
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_unknown_faster_rcnn_feature_extractor
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_unknown_faster_rcnn_feature_extractor
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_unknown_meta_architecture
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_unknown_meta_architecture
[ RUN      ] ModelBuilderTest.test_unknown_ssd_feature_extractor
[       OK ] ModelBuilderTest.test_unknown_ssd_feature_extractor
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 17 tests in 0.149s
```

But in my case it is not throwing any out put. Is it normal?
Here are my whole codes and output:

```
%cd /content
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

!apt-get install -qq protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk

!pip install -q Cython contextlib2 pillow lxml matplotlib

!pip install -q pycocotools

%cd /content/models/research

!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += ':/content/models/research/:/content/models/research/slim/'

!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py


/content
fatal: destination path 'models' already exists and is not an empty directory.
/content/models/research
```

Comment: I guess you did not executed `!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py` line. How ever i recommend you to follow steps for Object Detection model in TF2 using this [Colab notebook](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/drive/1sLqFKVV94wm-lglFq_0kGo2ciM0kecWD#scrollTo=wHfsJ5nWLWh9) by Roboflow. Thanks!